# Illustrate line on a ListContourPlot from lists of data

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to illustrate a line on a `ListContourPlot`. In particular, I have the following plot:

```
ListContourPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Contours -> 50, ColorFunction -> (If[# <= 0, Darker[Black, Abs[#]], Hue[#]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

where `data1` is a nest list of values (too large to attach here, but consider the example:
{ …, {0.5610, 0.05244, 0.1015}, {0.5610, 0.05344, 0.09612},
{0.5610, 0.05444, 0.09072}, {0.5610, 0.05549, 0.08536},
{0.5610, 0.05644, 0.08004}, {0.5610, 0.05744, 0.07476}, … }).

I have a separate list `data2`, which traces a line (again too large to attach). How can I illustrate the line corresponding to `data2` on top of the ContourPlot corresponding to `data1`? I would like the line to correspond to the same color range specified for the contour plot, but made thicker to distinguish it as data from the line `data2`.

**EDIT**

Note that the data lists have the structure: {{x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}, {x3,y3,z3}, ...} and {{x'1,y'1,z'1}, {x'2,y'2,z'2}, {x'3,y'3,z'3}, ...} for `data1` and `data2` respectively. A snippet is as follows:

```
data1 = {{0.485, 0.1023, 0}, {0.485, 0.1223, 0}, {0.505, 0.0884, 0.00575}, {0.505, 0.1084, 0}, {0.50508, 0.1284, 0}, {0.525, 0.0945, 0}, {0.525, 0.1145, 0}, {0.52508, 0.1345, 0}, {0.54508, 0.0805, 0}, {0.545, 0.1005, 0}, {0.545, 0.1205, 0}, {0.54508, 0.1405, 0}, {0.545, 0.1605, 0}}

data2 = {{0.4650, 0.1162, 0}, {0.4748, 0.1095, 0}, {0.4845, 0.1027, 0}, {0.4942, 0.0959, 0}, {0.50397, 0.0892, 0.0047}, {0.5136, 0.0824, 0.0151}, {0.5234, 0.0756, 0.0292}, {0.5331, 0.0689, 0.0468}, {0.5428, 0.0621, 0.0680}, {0.5525, 0.0553, 0.0930}, {0.5622, 0.0486, 0.1220}}
```

`data1` is a contour plot, while `data2` should be a line.

Comment: You can save your file to `GoogleDrive` or `OneDrive` etc. Create and subsequently post a public link to this file to get more concrete answers. Have you already explored `Show` and did it not work?

Comment: @Syed, thank you for your comment. I've added some further information on `data1` and `data2`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I interpreted you description correctly. You have 2 ListContourPlot, one showing some surface and the other only  a line. Concerning the color, as the line is a contour with a single value, it has a single color.

As you did not give some data, I create some arbitrary data:

```
dat = Table[i^2 + j^2, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
line = Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
```

With this:

Show[ListContourPlot[{dat}],
ListContourPlot[line, Contours -> 1, ContourShading -> None,
ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness -> 0.01]]]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `data1` has the structure `{{x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}, {x3,y3,z3}, ...}` and `data2` has the structure `{{x'1,y'1,z'1}, {x'2,y'2,z'2}, {x'3,y'3,z'3}, ...}`. Could you give a solution that matches this structure?

Comment: I have added some example data to the original questions.

Comment: If the data points are on a equal distant grid, ListContourPlot only needs the function values. Therefore use e.g.: `f1/@ data1`.

Comment: If by equal distant grid you mean the x' and y' values are sampled with uniform steps, then yes that's true. Could you provide an edit to your answer to illustrate this? Although the procedure for determining the `data2` list is different-would be preferred to overlay the line.

Comment: Simply put: `dat=f1/data1; line= f2/@data2;`